# Power Automate - get categories

Tags: power-automate

I'm new to Power Automate and trying to get the "Category" flag that is placed on emails after received.  My number one problem is finding a connection that has the category object available.
These are the objects I'm trying to find, in Outlook web they are 'category labels'
[image: Picture]

In web searches I'm getting contradictory information, one they can't be found: [Link](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Get-an-email-s-categories/td-p/506318)

Another says if you connect to Outlook365 you'll have 'Categories' [Link](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Flow-for-Category-on-Outlook-Event/td-p/307511), these may only be associated with calendar entries.

The Connections I've been able to make are to Shared Mailboxes, I'm now experimenting with my personal work mailbox (Outlook 365) and not finding it there either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [List Outlook categories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/outlookuser-list-mastercategories?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) Graph API method for this. Use the below Uri in a Send an HTTP request Outlook Office 365 connector action.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/outlook/masterCategories
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help Expiscornovus,
I already have a workflow that is pulling new emails.  I'd like to be able to update the emails with the categories that were applied (after received).  Is that even possible?
The Graph method suggested seems to pull the list of categories, not those assigned to each email